# Switching between in-memory and WCF service?

Tags: wcf, optimization

Imagine I have the following, standard WCF, code :

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ICustomerService {
    [OperationContract]
    Customer GetCustomer();
}

public ICustomerService {
     public Customer GetCustomer() 
     { 
          return MyStore.WhatIsNeeded();
     }
}
```

This is working well and allows me to distribute the service and the consuming code.

Is it possible (and is it a good idea) to completely bypass the WCF engine if working in a single box ?

In fact, I want the app to be able to run on farm servers, or on small single box servers.

To reduce WCF messaging cost, I'd like to have something like :

```
ICustomerService service = null;
if(singlebox)
{
    service = new CustomerService(); // Direct instanciation of the service class. No WCF here ...
}
else
{
    service = new CustomerServiceClient(); // Wcf client
}

var cust = service.GetCustomer();
```

If wrapped properly, can this technique reduce server charge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will surely reduce the overhead of WCF runtime. I'd create a factory class which will check if(singlebox) and new up the right implementation of ICustomerService.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because the client will be attempting to access an endpoint for a service that no longer is exposing one. The WCF plumbing is required for the both the service and the client. For single box scenarios, look at the [NetNamedPipeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576406.aspx) which is the WCF plumbing done through the equivalent of shared memory.

Comment: Did you notice that in the first case, I instantiate the service class directly ? These class is not inheriting any of the WCF class, only implement the interface. in this case, why does the service call should try to open an endpoint ?

Comment: But +1 for the NetNamedPipeBinding suggestion... this will be my fallback if pure object access is not possible

Comment: For the implementation class to run as a WCF service, it needs to be instantiated by a ServiceHost. If you are not using ServiceHost then yes, you're just creating a simple .NET class which can be called directly like any other .NET class. You'd be doing something similar to what unit testing a WCF Service Library project would do.